# mvc and web.api authorisation using oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

Seems like I am asking the same question that many have but can not fit everything together.
I have a standard MVC application configured with Oauth using the standard Identity DB, the user signs in and that all works fine, I then want to call the Web.API application as an authenticated user. From my research I have added the bearer token to the httpclient thinking that this would somehow be authorized in the web.api application I have set the Web.API application to point to the same identity db but im not sure what i am missing.  I've spent days on this and  no luck so any samples would be much appreciated.

the code to get the bearer token is

```
protected string GetToken()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, User.Identity.Name));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, User.Identity.GetClaimValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier.ToString())));
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
        ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
        string accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
        return accessToken;
    }
```

the call to the Web.APi is

```
var token = GetToken();
        string uri = UriEASOnlineApi + EASOnlineWebAPI.SignErectors;

        List<SignErector> result;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            var task = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (task.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var jsonString = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SignErector>>(jsonString);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception($"failed: {task.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know how authentication is done in WebApi. Then if you have working example of call to this WebApi e.g. from Postman or Fiddler you can compare manual request with the one you create programmatically from MVC application.